# Linux Shell Script if statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm studying Linux Shell script and learning the flow control

I'm stuck with this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=2

if [ $x=5 ]; then
        echo "x equals 5."
else
        echo "x does not equal 5."
fi
```

The only response I get on the terminal when executing the command is : x equals 5.

Can anyone help me to find the error in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`$x=5` is one string, interpreted as `"2=5"`, which is not zero, thus true.

`$x = 5` is two strings and a string equality operator between them, and evaluates to false.

However, this is a bit insecure, since in theory `$x` can be empty, in which case you get ungrammatical test `= 5`; the safe variant is `"$x" = 5`.

If you need to compare numbers, use `-eq` instead of `=`. For example, `05 = 5` is false, but `05 -eq 5` is true.

Comment: The key thing to remember, is that `[` is just a shell command (`/bin/[`, which is usually a link to `/bin/test`), and not a part of the shell syntax, You pass argument to the `[` command, (in this case, 4: the value of `$x`, `=`, `5`, and `]`; this is why the spaces are required.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Almost but no. The key thing to remember is how `bash` parses a command line. For example, `foo="a b"` (unrelated to `if` and `[`) defines a variable `foo` with a value `a b`; but `foo=a b` defines temporarily a variable `foo` to be `a`, and under that environment launches program `b`. The split-by-spaces happens when the command line is parsed, and has nothing to do with the fact that `[` is an executable. However, you are correct to the extent that each space-separated segment will be passed to `[` as a separate argument, and that `[` will not look for operators as substrings.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I follow you; in this case, there's a dollarsign. `$x=5` becomes `2=5`, and gets passed as-is to `[`, which can't parse it (or rather, just parses it as *True*). I also tested it with `[ x=5 ]`, it still gets passed to `[` as-is in BSD bourne shell & bash (using a shell script as `[` which has `echo $*`)... Perhaps your behaviour is true for other scenarios? Or maybe I didn't test is correctly?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: What do you mean, my behaviour? I believe we are not really disagreeing, except for my insisting that the split-by-spaces is not due to `[` being a command, and would have occurred even if it was a built-in, or a function, or even a part of syntax like its cousin `[[` is. `$x = 5` does not become `$x`, `=` and `5` because `[` is a command, but because `if [ $x = 5 ]; then` is a command line parsed by `bash`. The fact that `[` is a command, while interesting, is completely irrelevant here, evidenced by the fact that you can rewrite all these examples with `[[` with same results.

Answer (score 1):

use `-eq` rather than `=`:

```
if [ $x -eq 5 ]; then
        ^^^
```

`=` is string operator. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line
`if [ $x=5 ]; then`  to `if [ $x = 5 ]; then`.

The spaces are required for evaluation.

**Execution**

```
$ sh sample.sh 
x does not equal 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find out what shell you are actually talking about. If you go for the basic [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_14) (/bin/sh) syntax, then the basic form of if is calling a program and evaluating its return code. There is a special program `test` which is aliased to `[` which does the expressions. However this program requires all of the parts of the expression to be different arguments, and therefore you have to put blanks before and after the [, the $x, the = and the 5.